# Dump Critical Section Queue (Threads waiting)

Tags: c++, synchronization, windbg, critical-section

I have an issue (crash dump) where my Critical Section is being destroyed but after inspecting the LockCount I note that there is 1 thread waiting on it (it seems that the thread has been woken, but not yet entered, since lock status is Not Locked).

I want to see what thread has been woken. I know the Critical Section has a queue of waiting threads, if I could dump this queue/list structure I should be able to answer my question, any idea's on what I could do?

Comment: You should try to get the stack traces for all threads. Maybe this page would help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554943.aspx

Comment: Not sure I understand - what is destroying the CS?

Comment: @MartinJames Sorry for not being clear. The destructor of one of my objects is deleting the critical section (this is okay). But there is a thread that has been woken to acquire the CS somewhere else. Since the thread has just been woken, not entered the CS !cs -s address shows no thread owning the CS.

Answer (score 0):

the CriticalSection Object is defined as

```
typedef RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION CRITICAL_SECTION;
```

with `RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION` defined as

```
typedef struct _RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION {
    PRTL_CRITICAL_SECTION_DEBUG DebugInfo;
    LONG LockCount;
    LONG RecursionCount;
    HANDLE OwningThread;        // from the thread's ClientId->UniqueThread
    HANDLE LockSemaphore;
    ULONG_PTR SpinCount;        // force size on 64-bit systems when packed
} RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION, *PRTL_CRITICAL_SECTION;
```

*OwningThread* will contain a handle to the owning thread.
So you may just read the `CriticalSection` data structure to obtain the handle to the owning thread.

```
DWORD WINAPI GetThreadId(_In_ HANDLE OwningThread);
```

will return the ID of the owning thread.

*However, there is a small mishap with the definition of OwningThread. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164040.aspx) reports that field actually contains the thread ID itself.*

You may use

```
GetThreadInformation(OwningThread,....);
```

to obtain more thread details.

[Break Free of Code Deadlocks in Critical Sections Under Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164040.aspx) on MSDN is a **must read** in this context. Particulary the `EntryCount/ContentionCount` field in the `RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION_DEBUG` structure may give an answer to the question here.

Comment: This is what i usually do. However i get null for the OwningThread, but my LockCount suggests one thread is waiting and has been woken. I was thinking maybe it is yet to enter the CS.

Comment: I'm wondering whether there is a misunderstanding of LockCount. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164040.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: The meaning of LockCount changed slightly from Sever 2003 onwards. I'm pretty sure I've interpreted it correctly, I jut did a few bitness operations to work out the individual parts (i.e. thread status, thread woken and threads waiting for lock).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried !locks? There's info about viewing critical sections in a process in the WinDBG docs here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541979(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes I had. The problem is I know the address of the CS, and I know that it has no owning thread yet. I am thinking the thread has been woken but not yet entered the CS. I was hoping to find out the thread that was woken.